# Trait with Abstract Type in Method Argument

Tags: scala, types, subclass, traits, abstract-type

I am new to Scala and am building tools for statistical estimation. Consider the following: a trait `probabilityDistribution` is defined, which guarantees that classes which inherit from it will be able to perform certain functions, such as compute a density. Two such examples of probability distributions might be a binomial and beta distribution. The support of these two functions is `Int` and `Double`, respectively.

**Set Up**

```
trait probabilityDistribution extends Serializable {
  type T
  def density(x: T): Double
}

case class binomial(n: Int, p: Double) extends probabilityDistribution {
  type T = Int
  def density(x: Int): Double = x*p
}

case class beta(alpha: Double, beta: Double) extends probabilityDistribution {
  type T = Double
  def density(x: Double): Double = x*alpha*beta
}
```

Note that the actual mathematical implementations of the `density` methods are simplified above. Now, consider a Mixture Model, in which we have several features or variables which come from different distributions. We may choose to create a list of `probabilityDistribution`s to represent our features.

```
val p = List(binomial(5, .5), beta(.5,.5))
```

Suppose that we are now interested in supplying a vector of hypothetical data values, and wish to query the `density` functions for each respective probability distribution.

```
val v = List[Any](2, 0.75)
```

**The Problem**
Of course, we use a zip with map. However, this doesn't work:

```
p zip v map { case (x,y) => x.density(y) }
### found   : Any
  # required: x.T
```

**Caveat: Choice of Container**
A valid question is to wonder why I have chosen `List[Any]` as the container to hold data values, rather than `List[Double]`, or perhaps `List[T <: Double]`. Consider the case when some of our probability distributions have a support over vectors or even matrices (e.g. multivariate normal and inverse Wishart)

**An idea to address the caveat** might be to instead house our input values in a container that is more representative of our input type. e.g. something like

```
class likelihoodSupport
val v = List[likelihoodSupport](...)
```

where `Int`, `Double`, and `Array[Double]` and even a tuple `(Array[Double], Array[Array[Double]])` all inherit from `likelihoodSupport`. As some of these classes are final, however, this is not possible.

**One (Crummy) Fix**

Note that this can be handled by using pattern matching and a polymorphic method within each subclass, but as Odersky might say *this has a code smell*:

```
trait probabilityDistribution extends Serializable {
  type T
  def density[T](x: T): Double
}

case class binomial(n: Int, p: Double) extends probabilityDistribution {
  type T = Int
  def density[U](x: U): Double = x match {case arg: Int => arg * p }
}

case class beta(alpha: Double, beta: Double) extends probabilityDistribution {
  type T = Double
  def density[U](x: U): Double = x match {case arg: Double => arg * alpha * beta}
}
```

We can now run

```
p zip v map { case (x,y) => x.density(y) }
```

**Plea** I know what I'm trying to do should be very easily accomplished in such a beautiful and powerful language, but I can't figure out how! Your help is much appreciated.

**Note** I am not interested in using additional packages/imports, as I feel this problem should be trivially solved in base Scala.

Comment: Why not just use simple generics `ProbabilityDistribution[T]`?

Comment: For a list with known different types of elements there is an `HList` (in shapeless for instance).

Comment: My understanding is that "simple generics" doesn't buy anything; using an abstract type within the trait definition is equivalent in this case. Further, I am not interested in importing additional packages, as I feel this problem should be trivially solved in base scala.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it given the separate `p` and `v` lists (at least without casts, or by writing your own `HList` library). This should be obvious: if you change the order of elements in one of these lists, the types won't change (unlike for `HList`), but distributions will now be paired with values of a wrong type!

The simplest approach is to add a cast:

```
p zip v map { case (x,y) => x.density(y.asInstanceOf[x.T]) }
```

Note that this may be a no-op at the runtime and lead to a `ClassCastException` inside `density` call instead, thanks to JVM type erasure.

If you want a safer alternative to the cast, something like this should work (see http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html for more information on `ClassTags` and related types):

```
// note that generics do buy you some convenience in this case:
// abstract class probabilityDistribution[T](implicit val tag: ClassTag[T]) extends Serializable
// will mean you don't need to set tag explicitly in subtypes
trait probabilityDistribution extends Serializable {
  type T
  implicit val tag: ClassTag[T]
  def density(x: T): Double
}

case class binomial(n: Int, p: Double) extends probabilityDistribution {
  type T = Int
  val tag = classTag[Int]
  def density(x: Int): Double = x*p
}

p zip v map { (x,y) => 
  implicit val tag: ClassTag[x.T] = x.tag
  y match { 
    case y: x.T => ... 
    case _ => ... 
  }
}
```

Or you can combine distributions and values (or data structures containing values, functions returning values, etc.):

```
// alternately DistribWithValue(d: probabilityDistribution)(x: d.T)
case class DistribWithValue[A](d: probabilityDistribution { type T = A }, x: A) {
  def density = d.density(x)
}

val pv: List[DistribWithValue[_]] = List(DistribWithValue(binomial(5, .5), 2), DistribWithValue(beta(.5,.5), 0.75))

// if you want p and v on their own
val p = pv.map(_.d)
val v = pv.map(_.x)
```

Of course, if you want to use a `probabilityDistribution` as a *method argument*, as the question title says, it's simple, for example:

```
def density(d: probabilityDistribution)(xs: List[d.T]) = xs.map(d.density _)
```

The problems only arise specifically when

> The user may wish to make multiple density queries with different x values that are not intrinsically related to the probability distribution itself

and the compiler can't *prove* that these values have the correct type.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this approach is that I don't wish to _attach_ the value `x` to the object. The user may wish to make multiple `density` queries with different `x` values that are not intrinsically related to the probability distribution itself. With regard to the `asInstanceOf`, is it not possible to pattern match the type of `y` in the map due to type erasure?

Comment: In that case, as I've said, you need to either 1) resort to casts; 2) write your own `HList` or use an existing library; 3) don't have a list of probability distributions with different `T`s. I'll edit to answer your question.